# Why does this equality holds for any choice of basis in $\mathfrak{g}$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a lie group with lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $M$ be a $G$-manifold. We denote the space of smooth differential forms on $M$ by $A(M)$. Let $E^i$ be a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $E_i$ $\in \mathfrak{g}^*$ be the dual basis. Let $S(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ be the symmetric algebra of $\mathfrak{g}^*$.

Le $F^i$ be another basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ with dual basis $F_i$ $\in \mathfrak{g}^*$. Why the following equality holds:

$$\sum_i F_iP \otimes \iota (F^i_M) \alpha= \sum_i E_iP \otimes \iota (E^i_M) \alpha$$

for $P \in S(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ and $\alpha \in A(M)$ (note that $\iota (E^i_M)$ is the contraction by the vector field $E^i_M$ wich is defined by $$(E^i_M.f)(m)= \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0} f(\exp(tE^i)m),$$ for $f \in C^\infty(M)$ and $m \in M$).

I've tried to use the fact that $\sum_i F_i \otimes F^i= \sum_i E_i \otimes E^i$, in  $\mathfrak{g}\otimes \mathfrak{g}^*$,  but i get anywhere .